# Why sending mail is not working on my code ?

Tags: android

Trying to send mail with attached file - and i don't know why this code is not working .. the mail is not sending

```
public void SendMailWithAttached(String fileToSend, String mailToSend)
{  
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, fileToSend);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,mailToSend);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));

}
```

Comment: Did you have any error?

Comment: Do you have installed some mail sender? If not your intent chooser won't work.

Comment: no error - and i have installed mail sender

Comment: So problem is in your source code. what are you trying to do?

Comment: just attach file ( give file location as param ) and sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do to send a file as an attachment:

```
File effFile = new File(toPath, files[0]);
Uri effU = Uri.fromFile(effFile);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, effU);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email:"));
```

The i.setType("text/plain"); command didn't work when I tried others.